# Mongodb throwing No space left on device error intermittently

Tags: mongodb, nosql

MongoDB throwing following error in syslogs:-

LogFile::synchronousAppend failed with 16384 bytes unwritten out of 16384 bytes;  b=0x7fed27ffe000 errno:28 No space left on device Tue Jun 26 00:13:42 Got signal: 6 (Aborted)

It is a 64 bit Cent OS machine. My Disk Usage is 65% only.

One that happens, mongodb crashes and needs to be started again.

What is the problem and solution?

Comment: are you using 32 or 64-bit machine?

Comment: Do you have 32-bit machine and storing more than 2GB of data ?

Comment: Are you sure you have enough drive space?

Comment: machine-1 [root:/]$ df -k
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvde1            10321208   6287168   3509752  65% /  



machine-1 [root:/]$ uname -a
Linux xxxxxx 2.6.32-220.13.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Apr 17 23:56:34 BST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Did u check if u have any inode left on the disk? (df -i)

Comment: It's possible that you have some fragmentation on the file system, can you run a fsck?

Comment: It looks like your problem is caused by device not mongodb. I found a link that suggests a solution to this problem.See the solution on the link. Hope this will help you. http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=606486